# How to get Spring to print out what spring profiles are active?

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring 3.1 profiles and want would like Spring to print out on startup what profiles are active. For example are the first few lines of the output in the log file.

```
02:59:43,451 INFO  [ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
02:59:43,544 INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Dec 30 02:59:43 EST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
02:59:43,610 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
02:59:43,835 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-security.xml]
02:59:43,971 INFO  [SpringSecurityCoreVersion] You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.3.RELEASE
02:59:43,971 INFO  [SecurityNamespaceHandler] Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.3.RELEASE
```

What I want to see from spring is something that prints out the version of spring in use along with which profiles are currently active.

How can I get spring to printout it's version and what profiles are active?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Implement [`EnvironmentAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware.html) interface

For example

```
class MyEnvironmentAware implements EnvironmentAware{
    private static Environment env = null;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
            env = environment;
            //log the stuff you want here
     }
}
```

Mark this class as Spring bean

or

just inject [`Environment`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) in one of your eagerly loading bean and print the detail you need from it

like

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

in your eagerly loading bean, and print it

Answer (score 13):

You could get it by configuring log4j, as the `Environment` object logs the activating of the profile at `DEBUG` level.

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.core.env=DEBUG, A1
```

If `A1` is your log appender. Unfortunately, there is a lot of other stuff coming at DEBUG level, so it is not really nice, but you get the active profile without source modification.

The config logs in a standalone Swing app on startup:

```
58   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Activating profile 'production'
```

Note, this is fragile, as it relies on debug level logs, which can change rapidly in every commit to spring.

Comment: Didn't find that in Spring 3.2. But there is something like `DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:79 -  Found key 'spring.profiles.active' in [systemProperties] with type [String] and value 'dev,auth-dev,db-server,log-dev'`

Answer (score 10):

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
private String activeProfiles;
```

This will give you a string with active profiles.

If you include in your configuration DefaultFormattingConversionService:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService() {
    return new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
}
```

it will return a List of strings:

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
private List<String> activeProfiles;
```